# firebase pagination with autoId

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database

Like facebook, my app has post where people can comment. I want to achieve pagination for the comments in case they become big. I am using a simple code below to test out the function. Basically, when the user hit the test button, more comments printed out. All my comments entry are saved in firebase via childByAutoId. I saw somewhere online that I can sort chronologically using the autoID as they are generated like a timestamp. Attached is my firebase entry [image: firebaseEntry]

```
@IBAction func testBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var pageSize = 3
    var query = DataService.ds.REF_COMMENT.child(self.post.postKey).queryOrderedByKey()

    if startKey != nil {
        query = query.queryStartingAtValue(startKey)
        pageSize += 1
    }

    query.queryLimitedToFirst(UInt(pageSize)).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let comments = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                for comment in comments {
                    let commentKey = comment.0
                    let commentDict = comment.1

                    print("commentDict \(commentDict)")

                    self.startKey = commentKey
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No comments
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in the photo, I have several comments from 1 to 16 (From top of image to bottom is comment 1, comment 2, comment 3, .... etc) That is the order when it is entered in the firebase also.

So what I am expecting is when I hit the test button, I will get from the commentDict printout something in the order of

Comment1, Comment2, Comment 3.

Then when i press again, I will get

Comment 3, Comment 4, Comment 5

However, On the first press I am actually getting,

Comment 2, Comment 1, Comment 3.

On the 2nd press, I am getting

Comment 5, Comment 4, Comment 3

And every press after that is

Comment 5, Comment 4, Comment 3

1. Why is it not in the correct order the first time
2. Why is it showing a backward order every time after the first time?

Is the AutoId not doing what it suppose to do?

Thanks,

Comment: observer type `Value` takes all values at once and order is not fixed ...  so better to sort with date or use childAdded

Comment: Since my date is hidden inside the commentAutoID (comments-> post -> commentID -> [bumpCount, comment, commentOwner, date], does that mean I have to download ALL the data to figure out which one is the "earliest" comment then? I was hopping to use the autoID to allow firebase to take care of the business. I tried changing to childAdded but that just gives me weird values.